# Server 2012r2 DNS failover/load balance SOA entry

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, soa-record

I have 2 Server 2012r2 servers running DNS in failover/loadbalance. They both sync fine but I have noticed that they each claim themselves as SOA. It sounds wrong to me, but is this due to the failover?

Thanks,
Travis

Comment: `I have 2 Server 2012r2 servers running DNS in failover/loadbalance` - What does that mean exactly? How are they configured for failover/loadbalance?

Comment: My apologies, I was thinking of the DHCP setup. Realizing this, should the SOA on the 2nd DNS server point to the 1st DNS server?

Comment: Are these Domain Controllers hosting an AD integrated DNS zone? If so, then each server is SOA for it's copy of the zone and this is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AD integrated DNS zones, each server hosting a copy of the zone is the SOA for it's copy of the zone.

This is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

It is typical for systems that do not use DNS to replicate to claim themselves as master.  This is true for not only Windows (AD Integrated zones) but also bind (ldap-bind) and powerdns (ldap, database, etc).

More on [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282826/active-directory-integrated-dns-zone-serial-number-behavior) [Bind](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.4_Technical_Notes/bind-dyndb-ldap.html), and [PowerDNS](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/types/#soa)

I've asked this question as well, I expect as more people use APIs with multiple providers, the SOA and Serial # will continue to diverge.